# Actualizar lo datos automáticamente y evitar la inserción repetida de registros

Tags: mysql

disculpen tengo un dilema quiero actualizar datos de la tabla **"f_posts"** de las columnas "ID" Y "post_title" a la tabla **"f_quiz"** en las columnas "id_quiz" y "quiz" pero hacerlo de forma automática sin repetir datos existentes en mysql.
Este es mi consulta para insertar los datos, pero yo quisiera un triger donde los actualizara sin repetirlos los registros.

```
INSERT INTO f_quiz (`Id_quiz`,`quiz`) SELECT `ID`,`post_title`FROM f_posts;
```

EJEMPLO DE UPDATE (ESTA MAL LA SINTAXIS)

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `dato`;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `dato` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `f_posts` 
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            UPDATE INTO `f_quiz` (`Id_quiz`,`quiz`) SELECT (NEW.`ID`,NEW.`post_title`);
        END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

alguna idea de como realizarlo, sino se puede con un Tigger, como lo haria con una consulta manual???

Comment: son ideas mias o quiere duplicar la tabla?

Comment: puedes compartir tu escenario completo aqui:  http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a definir tu disparador así:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `dato`;
CREATE TRIGGER `dato` 
  AFTER INSERT ON `f_posts`
  FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO `f_quiz` (`Id_quiz`,`quiz`)
    VALUES (NEW.`ID`,NEW.`post_title`);
```

Se pueden realizar las comprobaciones en este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE f_quiz(
  `Id_quiz` int,
  `quiz` varchar(127)
  );
CREATE TABLE f_posts(
  `ID` int,
  `post_title` varchar(127)
  );
```

Y con esta inserción de prueba:

```
INSERT INTO f_posts (ID, post_title)
  VALUES (2,'TEST2');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda bro :3